# How do you reference a viewmodel from a CustomControl using MVVM light

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

I'm used to setting the datacontext of a *UserControl* in xaml to a viewmodel using the MVVM-light locator. e.g:

```
DataContext="{Binding SplashMainViewModel, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
```

This is done in the view's markup in xaml.

How does one go about setting the datacontext of a *CustomControl* to a viewmodel? In VS the custom control is created with the following:

```
    public class CustomControl1 : Control
    {
        static CustomControl1()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomControl1),new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomControl1)));
        }
    }
```

But it doesn't have the usual xaml markup.

Comment: Can you make your question vore clear? You want to set `CustomViewModel` to `CustomControl`?

Comment: A custom control often has a Style in `Themes\Generic.xaml`. You may perhaps set the DataContext there (provided that the Locator resource is available there). Otherwise, you should be able to set it in the control's constructor. Or just don't set it all, and let it be inherited or set explicitly when the control is instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
public class CustomControl1 : Control
{
    static CustomControl1()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomControl1),new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomControl1)));
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
          base.OnApplyTemplate();
          DataContext = ((MyLocatorType)Resources["Locator"]).SplashMainViewModel;
    }
}
```

... or set it in the XAML of the template (`Themes\Generic.xaml`).

Answer (score 0):

Rico Suter's demonstrates how to set CustomControl1's DataContext for all instances of CustomControl1. I'm guessing this is what you want to do.

You could use your normal approach to set the DataContext on a specific  instance of CustomControl1 (in the xaml where it is declared). I'm guessing this is not what you want to do but I'm including for completeness. If there is only one instance of CustomControl1 this may be more convenient.

Comment: I'm likely to have this control repeating within an itemsControl datatemplate - so I would need to bind a specific instance to the control to it's own viewmodel.